# How to hash DataFrame column to SHA256?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hash, iterator

I have a dataframe column that is coming from Teradata.  I want to hash this column according to SHA256 standards, but I keep getting an error.  Here is my code:

```
import os, teradata, teradatasql
import pandas as pd
import hashlib
db = ckdb.TConn(True)

pin = '''select email from ctt.cnsmr_emlid'''

a = db.execute(pin)

rows = []
for i in a:
    rows.append(i)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.columns = [['email']]

def hash_unicode(a_string):
    return hashlib.sha256(a_string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

df['email_1'].apply(hash_unicode)
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Try `map` instead of `apply`.

Comment: @Learningisamess Why? Problem for the error lies in `df.columns = [['email']]`; double brackets make the columns a MultiIndex (e.g., see `print(df.columns)`) and therefore `df.email_1` is not a Series but still a DataFrame, hence the error from `apply`. You might want to get rid of one pair of `[]` there.

Comment: @Neither indeed I had missed the double brackets. If you don't need a multiIndex drop it here

Comment: Otherwise `applymap` instead of `apply` could work with MultiIndex. It applies a map entrywise.